# how to understand this gramma? case streamingRelation@StreamingRelation(dataSourceV1, sourceName, output)

Tags: scala

I am confused about this gramma while reading the source code of structured Streaming.

In microBatchExecution.scala

```
val _logicalPlan = analyzedPlan.transform {
     case streamingRelation@StreamingRelation(dataSourceV1, sourceName, 
output) =>
    toExecutionRelationMap.getOrElseUpdate(streamingRelation, {
      // Materialize source to avoid creating it in every batch
      val metadataPath = s"$resolvedCheckpointRoot/sources/$nextSourceId"
      val source = dataSourceV1.createSource(metadataPath)
      nextSourceId += 1
      logInfo(s"Using Source [$source] from DataSourceV1 named 
'$sourceName' [$dataSourceV1]")
      StreamingExecutionRelation(source, output)(sparkSession)
    })
……
 }
```

> **My Question:**
>
> 1. how to understand case streamingRelation@StreamingRelation(dataSourceV1, sourceName, output)?
> 2. what's the function of "@" here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many different ways you can do pattern matching:

You can capture the whole object by type to variable:

```
 case streamingRelation: StreamingRelation => 
     //do something with object of type StreamingRelation bound to variable streamingRelation
```

or you can deconstruct it:

```
case StreamingRelation(dataSourceV1, sourceName, output) => 
    //do something with members of an object like dataSourceV1, sourceName etc.
```

Syntax with `@` combines both:

```
case streamingRelation@StreamingRelation(dataSourceV1, sourceName, output) =>
  //both whole object is available as streamingRelation and all matched members like dataSourceV1, sourceName
```